# Nebenbedeutung von "stemmen"

Tags: meaning

**Beispiele:**

> *Diesen Job hätte ich nie stemmen können.*
>
> *Diese Aufgabe ist nicht zu stemmen.*

Aus dem Kontext kann ich entnehmen, dass *"stemmen"* hier im Sinne von *"bewältigen, gerecht werden"* verwendet wird.

Diese Bedeutung ist jedoch weder [im Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/stemmen) noch im [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/stemmen) aufgelistet.

**Handelt es sich hierbei um ein umgangssprachliches Verb oder gibt es anderweitige Gründe dafür?**

Comment: Wenn du schon einen Link zum DWDS setzt, dann solltest du auch »DWDS« schreiben, und nicht »Wiktionary«. Ich habe das für dich korrigiert.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unter

> > **BEDEUTUNGEN, BEISPIELE UND WENDUNGEN**
> >     ...
> >
> > ## 3.
> >
> > ...
> >     **b.** (etwas Großes, Schwieriges) bewältigen; erfolgreich durchführen
> >     **Beispiel** 
> >     *ein Projekt, eine Finanzierung stemmen*

in Deinem [Duden Link](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/stemmen) ist exakt diese (Neben-)Bedeutung aufgeführt.

> **Handelt es sich hierbei um ein umgangssprachliches Verb oder gibt es anderweitige Gründe dafür?**

Es steht weder *salopp*, *ugs.* oder Ähnliches dabei. Ich würde also sagen:
**Nein, es ist keine umgangsprachliche Bedeutung.**

---

Ich werde in meinem beruflichen Alltag als Software Entwickler sehr häufig gefragt, ob wir ein bestimmtes Vorhaben im Team innerhalb eines gegebenen Zeitlimits *stemmen* können.

Die Frage, ob ich persönlich in der Lage wäre, ein bestimmtes Gewicht mit meinen Armen in die Höhe zu *stemmen* betrifft mich eher seltener. Wenn, dann fragt meistens keiner, sondern ich stehe einfach nur alleine blöd da.